# Does a Grease spell affect the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

Does a grease spell affect where the caster is standing, or the caster in general when cast on itself? I've read of some rules about AOE spells not affecting the point of origin or something... but would like to know RAW

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, a *Grease* spell targeted so that the caster is included in its AoE will affect the target. *Grease* affects every creature within an area, making no exception for its caster:

> When the grease appears, each creature standing in
>   its area must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or fall
>   prone.

Spells with an AoE of cube, cone, or line do not affect their point of origin, but *Grease* is not any of those.

Comment: **Any** spell that does not specifically says "*the caster is unaffected*" or something to that effect will do its baddies on the caster, if he is inside the effect.

Comment: And affect allies too, careful with that fireball please.